# Attaching Debugger to Process On Remote Machine

Tags: azure, remote-debugging, iis-8

I need to attach a debugger to a process on remote machine on which my website is hosted in IIS.  What is the name of the process to which I should attach it.  I cannot see the name of my website or any obvious IIS process.  Alternatively how can I find out it. Thanks. Learner.For.Ever

Comment: Clarification: I want to debug an issue with a website/web role in azure.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found it: w3wp.exe

Learner.For.Ever